# Why can't I install WebORB?

Tags: .net, windows, weborb

I downloaded WeborbSetup3.6.0.3.zip from www.themidnightcoders.com and when I try to install it all I get is

> The installer was interupted before
>   WebORB for .NET 3.6.0.3 could be
>   installed. You need to restart the
>   installer to try again.
>
> Click "Close" to exit.

And this is on Windows 7 RC1, but a friend of mine also had the exact same problems, but on Windows Vista. And we really have no clue of what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just encountered the same problem and was able to get in work (Windows 7 RTM):

http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/developer-den/technical-articles/installing-weborb-on-vista-iis-7-install.html

It's now running fine on Windows 7 with VS 2008.

Good luck!